# How throw exception when laravel form request failed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I use Laravel-Form-Request and i have two question:

1- as i create form request, to validate it from controller, i can't use

```
$request->validated()
```

and when i use it error said : `Call to a member function validated() on null`

and when i use

```
$request->validate()
```

there is no problem. But in [Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests) said use `validated()`.  So where is the problem?

2- As i said i use `validate()` and when everything(rules) is ok continue but when there is problem in matching rules just redirect to current page but  i want to throw exception. how can i define that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$request->validated` when  you want to retrieve content of the request body which have been validated and not to validate the request. To perform the request validation It's always the `validate` method

```
$rules = [];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

if($validator->passes()){
    // here you will get all validated data
    $request_data = $request->validated();
}
```

If you want to throw an exception you have `fails` method on `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` Facade so you want check if the validation fails and throw you exception like this

```
if($validator->fails())}{
    throw new ThrowANewExceptionHere("Exception Message");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answering, so how can i throw exception, for example 4xx error when ```failed validation``` from form-request ?

Comment: You can call `abort(XXX)` which will return the corresponding laravel error page or a custom one